# How to Represent $L=-8\partial_1^2+4\partial_1\partial_2-\partial^2_2+3\partial_2$ as a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

> Hi. I am trying to determine if $L=-8\partial_1^2+4\partial_1\partial_2-\partial^2_2+3\partial_2$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is elliptic.

The easiest way I can think of doing this is to find the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix that corresponds to $L$. I know that if we have an operator of the form $$P=a\partial_1^2+b\partial_2^2\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b
  \end{bmatrix}.$$
But  I do not know how to form a symetric matrix for $L$. 
Thank you kindly.

Comment: Do you understand how $$P = a \partial_{1}^{2} +  b \partial_{2}^{2}$$ yields the matrix $A$? If so, then the answer should be clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually do now understand this and have taken it for granted. I would really enjoying knowing why this is.

Comment: is it by Fourier transform?

Comment: are you asking me or @Mattos ?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith I don't know what you mean by 'I actually do now understand this.. I would really enjoying knowing why this is'. You _do_ understand the relationship between $P$ and $A$ or you _don't_?

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand how $$P=a\partial_1^2+b\partial_2^2\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: You might want to look up quadratic forms. Either way, you have \begin{align} P &= a \partial_{1}^{2} + b \partial_{2}^{2} \\ &= [\partial_{1}, \partial_{2}] \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a \partial_{1} \\ b \partial_{2} \end{bmatrix} \\ &=  [\partial_{1}, \partial_{2}] \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \partial_{1} \\ \partial_{2} \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \boldsymbol{\partial} A \boldsymbol{\partial} \end{align}

Comment: Oh I see. For the general case in $\mathbb{R^3}$, does $$L=a\partial_1^2+b\partial_2^2+c\partial_3^2+d\partial_1\partial_2+e\partial_1\partial_3+f\partial_2\partial_3\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & \frac{d}{2} & \frac{e}{2} \\
    \frac{d}{2} & b & \frac{f}{2} \\  \frac{e}{2} & \frac{f}{2} & c  \\
  \end{bmatrix}, \ \text{for constants} \ a,b,c,d,e,f?$$